# Finding the angle a vector makes with the 'horizontal'

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products, angle

Suppose a cable car moves with direction vector $\vec{d}$ = $$\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
-2\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The question asks, "at what angle to the horizontal does the cable car travel?".
By horizontal, if you assume the x-axis, the angle can be found using $$\frac{|\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}|}{|\vec{a}\vec{b}|}$$)
Using this, the angle I find between $\vec{d}$ and $$\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The angle I find is $48.2^\circ$.
If I use the z-vector instead:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
The angle I find is $70.5^\circ$

The answer is $\approx 19.5^\circ$. How would I get this value?

Additional information:
The cable car starts at $(10,3,0)$ and it moves in the direction of $\vec{d}$ at a speed of $4.5 \;m\,s^{-1}$

Comment: I get none of these values, calculating the tangent of the angle of the directing vector and its projection on the $(x,y)$-plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find the angle between $\vec{d}$ and the projection of $\vec{d}$ onto the horizontal plane, which is the vector $\vec{p}=(2,-2,0)$. Try to apply the same equation with those two vectors.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I didn't completely understand. Why is it not the horizontal axis, but a plane? Also, why is the horizontal here the x-y plane, why not x-z or y-z?

Comment: It's a matter of conventions. Typically the angle formed "with the horizontal" means "with the horizontal plane", and the horizontal plane is considered to be the one defined by the equation $z=0$

Answer (score 3):

'Horizontal' here means the $x,y$ plane.

If you sketch a picture, it could be clear that the angle of a vector and a plane and the angle with a normal vector of the plane adds up to $90^\circ$.

So, since you already found the angle with the $z$-axis to be $70.5^\circ$, the angle to the horizontal will be $90^\circ-70.5^\circ=19.5^\circ$.